# Prestashop frontend checkbox don't send a POST values

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I use this html code in a page .tpl

```
<input name="prova" type="checkbox" id="prova" value="1" checked="checked">
```

and in php page use

```
'prova' => Tools::getValue('prova')
```

to get a checkbox value,

but when I try to print it is empty

Comment: Can you please edit the question to specify the file names that you have edited (e.g. which PHP file) and also how are you checking if it's really empty

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the form without checking checkbox, then browser will not send checkbox value. To check whether the checkbox is submitted or not, use the below code:

```
'prova' => Tools::getValue('prova', false);
```

If the checkbox is not submitted then it will return **false** otherwise return either the "**on**" or "**1**" value for that checkbox.